# Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I've seen other similar topics here on SO but none to seem to be directly addressing my problem.
Due to this [issue](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3189) I'm connecting to my EC2 instance via SSH rather than via Docker-Machine API.

I've got `docker-compose.yml` file in the running instance:

When executed I get:

`ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?`

`systemctl status docker` gives me:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
             └─10-machine.conf
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-11-26 13:57:22 UTC; 1h 21min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 605 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 12
     Memory: 125.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─605 /usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --storage-driver overlay2 --tlsverify --tlscacert /etc/doc
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on the instance and this is the Dockerfile that's being executed:

```
from python:3.8.2-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y netcat build-essential cmake xclip libsm6 libxext6 libgl1-mesa-glx && apt-get clean

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The file is successfully executed and containers spun up locally. What am I missing here ?

Comment: What machine are you running the command from?  Is the `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable set?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm running it from the instance. Connected through SSH. When I `echo`ed `$DOCKER_HOST` it printed out nothing. What should I set it to ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a docker group (if not already) and add your username to it.

1. Create a docker group.

   ```
     $ sudo groupadd docker
   ```
2. Next add your user to a docker group.

   ```
     $ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
   ```
3. After that log out and log back in so that the group membership is re-evaluated.

   Next verify that you can docker commands without sudo.

   ```
     $ docker run hello-world
   ```

If it shows 'Hello from Docker!', your installation is proper.